# React Native not starting iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

It happened recently when i tried `react-native run-ios`. Everything works fine in the terminal. no errors. even build get succeedded and in the terminal it says Launching `build.xxx.xxx` and then nothing happens. Loading dependency graph also 100% done.

i tried unistalling and re installing npm. but it didnt work

Comment: Have you tried running it via XCode?

Comment: No i havent. But im sure it will work. Even android works.but opening with xcode wont solve the problem. I wont be able to use live reload? Right?

Comment: Not sure if xcode will solve your problem, but you can use live reload too

Comment: Yes it did work with Xcode with live reload too.

Answer (score 0):

try to specify the phone simulator, for example: react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios

Answer (score 0):

It not like a real solution, but you might try

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Sometimes OSx "forgets" that xcode actually exists, especially if you migrated to new machine :(